# How to re-install 22.04LTS without reformatting disk or overwriting /home, /opt, and the like

Tags: upgrade, ssd, boot-repair

When I have gone from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS, the upgrade has been done in place without requiring a "blank" harddrive and without damaging non-system directories such as `/home`, `/opt`, `/usr/local`, and the like.  When I moved from a 2TB harddrive with a fully working 22.04LTS system plus environment I like to a 4TB SSD by doing a fresh install on the 4TB drive including the proprietary Nvidia packages supplied by Ubuntu, everything worked, from the GUI login to choosing MATE as my GUI, etc. I then did as root a `cp -prav` of the non-system directories from the 2TB drive accessed through a USB adapter to the 4TB drive.  After the `cp`, the GUI login and MATE no longer work, although MATE was working on the system before the `cp`.  I did NOT touch `/bin`, `/etc` `/sbin`, and the like.  I did copy my old root home `/root` so that things would work as I want.  Rather than attempting to find what is "broken", I would like to (re)install 22.04LTS over the existing 22.04LTS as an UPGRADE. not re-formatting any disk nor changing the non-system directories.  I have a bootable USB attached drive from which I install 22.04LTS (and that I boot as a trial mode on a hardware platform to verify that a computer under consideration that is not "Linux certified" will have fully usable hardware under Ubuntu LTS) -- can I use this USB drive or must I (re)install/upgrade from the web?  I suspect that there is a command line method to do this "upgrade re-install" rather than a full install, even if there is no actual upgrade involved (my 22.04LTS on the 4TB SSD is current according to the GUI Software Updater), and there may also be a GUI method.

NOTE:  [How to Reinstall Ubuntu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/reinstall-ubuntu)
JPEG excerpt attached[image: image of webpage]

shows a Reinstall option that does NOT overwrite "personal" files, but only system files.  That option does *NOT* appear when I follow the procedure detailed in the above URL.  Can this sort of action be done by other means or is there a different GUI installer for Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Comment: The above is correct:  the entire stock distro 22.04LTS current.  Overwrite, not format, not change non-systems files.  What is/are the command/s, including settings/options/switches, either command line interface or GUI?

Comment: I just edited my question showing what I found on the web that is NOT available when I attempt to Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 from a bootable USB installation drive that is a copy of the installation .iso from Ubuntu.  If there is a mechanism to "activate" what is shown in my edited question, please supply the commands, either from a command line interface or a GUI.